# How to Properly deploy Angular App with custom base path?

Tags: angular, nginx, angular-cli, angular-routing

I want to be able to use a distinctive path for different versions of my application:

`ng build --base-href=/whatever/ --deploy-url=/whatever/ --prod --build-optimizer`

And then host that on nginx with

```
location /whatever {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

If i try to use the ng build command with helpers I get this:

```
runtime.c88d7988090c0cf17003.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

I wanted to have this in place:

```
localhost:xxxx/master/
localhost:xxxx/testing
```

Any ideas? What am I missing?

Comment: @JoelJoseph I don't think the problem is on my NGINX config, unless I am doing something wrong. I pasted the nginx conf for context, I feel like the issue is with angular.